# How many times are DoFn's constructed?

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm using the apache beam python SDK and Dataflow to write an inference pipeline for making predictions with TensorFlow models. I have the prediction step in a DoFn, but I don't want to have to load the model every time I process a bundle because that's very expensive. From the docs [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/ParDo.html), "If required, a fresh instance of the argument DoFn is created on a worker, and the DoFn.Setup method is called on this instance. This may be through deserialization or other means. A PipelineRunner may reuse DoFn instances for multiple bundles. A DoFn that has terminated abnormally (by throwing an Exception) will never be reused." I've noticed that if I write my code like this

```
class StatefulGetEmbeddingsDoFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, model_dir):
         self.model = None # initialize
         self.model_dir = model_dir

    def process(self, element):
         if not self.model: # load model if model hasn't been loaded yet
             global i
             i += 1
             logging.info('Getting model: {}'.format(i))
             self.model = Model(saved_model_dir=self.model_dir)


         ids, b64 = element
         embeddings = self.model.predict(b64)

         res = [
            {
                'image': _id,
                'embeddings': embedding.tolist()
            } for _id, embedding in zip(ids, embeddings)
         ]
         return res
```

It seems like the model is being loaded more than once on every worker (I've got a cluster of ~30-40 machines). Is there a way of preventing the model from being loaded more than once? I would've expected this DoFn to only be constructed once on every machine but from the logs, it seems like that's not the case...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but my initial thoughts are to use the `setup` and `start_bundle` methods.

https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.setup